# Do Kubernetes NetworkPolicies block NodePort traffic?

Tags: kubernetes

I can't find in the official [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) whether `NetworkPolicy` block `NodePort` ingress traffic.

```
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          role: frontend
```

Considering the NetworkPolicy above - is it expected that it'll block any ingress traffic to `NodePort`-type services within my namespace?

If so, how do I allow such traffic into my namespace? Will [`ipBlock`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.12/#ipblock-v1-networking-k8s-io) solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do Kubernetes NetworkPolicies block NodePort traffic?

Not really.

As it says in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/): "*is a specification of how groups of **pods**...*".   Basically, they are applied to pods or group of pods. `NodePort` is defined in Kubernetes as a type of [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).

You can restrict traffic applying the Network Policy to your namespace and specifying **ipBlock** as you mentioned. This will specifically restrict traffic to your pods but not the NodePort. (It may be all that you need)

To restrict traffic to NodePorts you will have to use an alternative external solution and it will really depend on your setup. For example, if you are using a cloud provider like AWS you could use [security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html).

Alternatively, GCP provides [Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cloud-armor-backendconfig) with a Backend Config that allows you to control traffic to a service/ingress.